# View and complex query count distinct locations employee stayed in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a view which looks like this `view_1`:

```
id      Office              Begin_dt    Last_dt    Days
1       Office1            2019-09-02   2019-09-08  6   
1       Office2            2019-09-09   2019-09-30  21
1       Office1            2019-10-01   2019-10-31  30  
5       Office3            2017-10-01   2017-10-16  15  
5       Office2            2017-10-17   2017-10-30  13
5       Office2            2017-11-01   2017-11-31  30
```

I want to find the office where employee stayed for max time and also the number of Distinct Office locations he stayed in.

Expected output

```
id      Max_time_in_Office Days      Distinct_office_locations
1       Office1            36             2
5       Office2            43             2
```

So id 1 spends 6 and 30, overall 36 days in office 1. Max time is spent in office 1 by him. Distinct locations are 2.
id 5 spends 13 and 30 , 43 days in office. Max time is spent in office 2. Distinct locations are 2.

Code tried

```
select v.*
from (select v.id, v.office, sum(days) as Max_time_in_Office, count(Office) as Distinct_office_locations,
      rank() over (partition by id order by sum(days) desc) as seqnum
      from view_1 v
      group by id, office
     ) v
where seqnum = 1;
```

Output obtained

```
id      Max_time_in_Office Days      Distinct_office_locations
1       Office1            36             1
5       Office2            43             1
```

So I am getting wrong output. Can someone pls help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Close.  You want a window function:

```
select v.*
from (select v.id, v.office, sum(days) as Max_time_in_Office,
             count(*) over (partition by id) as Distinct_office_locations,
             rank() over (partition by id order by sum(days) desc) as seqnum
      from view_1 v
      group by id, office
     ) v
where seqnum = 1;
```

Basically the window function is counting the number of rows returned after the aggregation -- and there is one row per office.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the apply operator to achieve that:

```
select  V.Id, 
        T.Max_Time_Office, 
        T.Days, 
        Distinct_office_locations = count(distinct V.Office)
from view_1 V
Cross apply
(
    Select  top 1   Id,
                    Max_Time_Office = Office,
                    Days = sum(Days)
    From view_1 VG
    where V.Id = VG.Id
    group by VG.Id, VG.Office
    order by sum(Days) desc
) T 
group by V.Id, T.Max_Time_Office, T.Days
```

Basically, you are getting the Office with most days in the **order by sum(Days) desc** inside the Cross apply, and using that in the outer expression. I then just did a **count(distinct V.Office)** to get the distinct offices.